# How to deploy a war and an application on Openshift

Tags: maven, openshift

I am following [this](https://blog.openshift.com/build-your-own-google-maps-and-more-with-geoserver-on-openshift/) tutorial to install Geoserver on an Openshift application. The problem is that for the Geoserver (a .war) to run, I have to delete the src folder and the pom.xml from the application, but I need to develop an application there too.

So, how can I mantain the pom.xml and the src folder while having the WAR running (I really need to delete those things in order to get the war running)? Is it even possible?

With src folder and pom.xml I receive this response from Openshift:

```
remote: [INFO] ----------    --------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] Building test 1.0
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO]
remote: [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ test ---
remote: [INFO]
remote: [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ test ---
remote: [debug] execute contextualize
remote: [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
remote: [INFO] Copying 1 resource
remote: [INFO]
remote: [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ test ---
remote: [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
remote: [INFO]
remote: [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ test ---
remote: [debug] execute contextualize
remote: [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
remote: [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/openshift/56f18c457628e1639500003d/app-root/runtime/repo/src/test/resources
remote: [INFO]
remote: [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ test ---
remote: [INFO] No sources to compile
remote: [INFO]
remote: [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ test ---
remote: [INFO] Tests are skipped.
remote: [INFO]
remote: [INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ test ---
remote: [INFO] Packaging webapp
remote: [INFO] Assembling webapp [test] in [/var/lib/openshift/56f18c457628e1639500003d/app-root/runtime/repo/target/test]
remote: [INFO] Processing war project
remote: [INFO] Copying webapp resources [/var/lib/openshift/56f18c457628e1639500003d/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/webapp]
remote: [INFO] Webapp assembled in [93 msecs]
remote: [INFO] Building war: /var/lib/openshift/56f18c457628e1639500003d/app-root/runtime/repo/webapps/ROOT.war
remote: [INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] Total time: 4.278s
remote: [INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 22 14:31:40 EDT 2016
remote: [INFO] Final Memory: 8M/111M
remote: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is a3cec3f4
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Starting Postgres cartridge
remote: Postgres started
remote: Emptying tmp dir: /var/lib/openshift/56f18c457628e1639500003d/jbossews//tmp/Geotools
remote: Starting jbossews cartridge
remote: Found 127.3.185.129:8080 listening port
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

My pom.xml is the default pom.xml that Openshift supplies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eap</id>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>eap</id>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
                invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
                will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'webapps' 
                folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>test</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Posdata: I know how to get the war to run in its own context (http://test-testdomain.rhcloud.com/war/ for example).

**Update**: here is my `rhc tail -a geoserver`

```
==> app-root/logs/postgresql.log <==
2016-03-23 12:51:43 GMT LOG:  shutting down
2016-03-23 12:51:43 GMT LOG:  database system is shut down
2016-03-23 12:52:01 GMT LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Permission denied
2016-03-23 12:52:01 GMT LOG:  trying another address for the statistics collector
2016-03-23 12:52:01 GMT LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Cannot assign requested address
2016-03-23 12:52:01 GMT LOG:  disabling statistics collector for lack of working socket
2016-03-23 12:52:01 GMT WARNING:  autovacuum not started because of misconfiguration
2016-03-23 12:52:01 GMT HINT:  Enable the "track_counts" option.
2016-03-23 12:52:01 GMT LOG:  database system was shut down at 2016-03-23 12:51:43 GMT
2016-03-23 12:52:01 GMT LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

==> app-root/logs/jbossews.log <==
Mar 23, 2016 8:52:49 AM org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener contextDestroyed
INFO: Cleaned up javabean caches
Mar 23, 2016 8:52:50 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/geoserver] registered the JDBC driver [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Mar 23, 2016 8:52:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/openshift/56f28b760c1e66c08b000209/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/geoserver.war has finished in 40,390 ms
Mar 23, 2016 8:52:50 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.3.223.1-8080"]
Mar 23, 2016 8:52:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 44333 ms
```

Also, I have checked the ${OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_DIR}webapps, and I have the `geoserver.war` and the `ROOT.war`.

**Update 2**: after the touch command, I `rhc til -a geoserver` again and got:

```
==> app-root/logs/postgresql.log <==
2016-03-23 14:46:22 GMT LOG:  shutting down
2016-03-23 14:46:22 GMT LOG:  database system is shut down
2016-03-23 14:46:40 GMT LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Permission denied
2016-03-23 14:46:40 GMT LOG:  trying another address for the statistics collector
2016-03-23 14:46:40 GMT LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Cannot assign requested address
2016-03-23 14:46:40 GMT LOG:  disabling statistics collector for lack of working socket
2016-03-23 14:46:40 GMT WARNING:  autovacuum not started because of misconfiguration
2016-03-23 14:46:40 GMT HINT:  Enable the "track_counts" option.
2016-03-23 14:46:40 GMT LOG:  database system was shut down at 2016-03-23 14:46:22 GMT
2016-03-23 14:46:40 GMT LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

==> app-root/logs/jbossews.log <==
Mar 23, 2016 10:47:54 AM org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener contextDestroyed
INFO: Cleaned up javabean caches
Mar 23, 2016 10:47:57 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/geoserver] registered the JDBC driver [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Mar 23, 2016 10:47:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/openshift/56f28b760c1e66c08b000209/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/geoserver.war has finished in 68,308 ms
Mar 23, 2016 10:47:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.3.223.1-8080"]
Mar 23, 2016 10:47:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 72395 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openshift applications include a git repository to store the source code as a folder inside every application you create, after you push to the repository, if you `ssh` into your application, the repository is located at `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR`.

Every time you push to the repository of your application, a series of scripts, named [action hooks](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/action-hooks.html) in Openshift terminology, are run. The included action hooks vary deppending on what cartridge have you chosen.

One of the things that happens after a push in a java application server cartridge, is that a maven build is triggered, and the contents at `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR` (src folder and pom.xml) are used to create the `WAR` artifact, which is also automatically deployed on the application server included in the selected cartridge.

This basically means that you just need to push your source code to the repo, and Openshift will handle everything. You don't need to worry about deleting anything at all. In fact, if you delete the contents of the repository directory, there is nothing to build the artifact from.

If you have chosen a Do It Yourself (DIY) cartridge, you are in charge of managing everything, there aren't any scripts or action hooks included.

---

**Update**: It is possible to have both in the same gear, but some tweaks are required.

First, your application, the important bit is that in your pom.xml, keep the `<profile>` section, at least the `openshift` profile as it is, because on a push event, it will trigger a maven build with the `openshift` profile, which will generate a WAR artifact of your application, and generate a file named `ROOT.war` in the `webapps` directory.  This file will be copied from the repository to the tomcat deployment directory.

Now regarding the geoserver, in the repository from the guide, it gives you the file `ROOT.war` as the geoserver application:

1. You need to rename it to something else, as the triggered maven build will generate a ROOT.war file of your application, unless you modify the configuration of the `maven-war-plugin`.
2. You need to copy that renamed war file to the tomcat deployment directory. In order to do that, you need to use an **action hook**. In this case the `deploy` stage seems the appropiate one.

You need to create a file in the `.openshift/action_hooks` directory, named `deploy` and give it execution permissions (`chmod +x`) and include it in the version control, so it will get pushed to the gear along with your application. The file have to contain a script with the instructions to copy the geoserver WAR file to the deployment directory, assuming that you renamed the WAR as geoserver.war, and resides in the webapps directory, this script will do:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Deploying Geoserver application..." 
cp ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}webapps/geoserver.war ${OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_DIR}/webapps/
```

---

**Update** : I've tried to reproduce the problem following the guide and applying the tweeks i've mentioned, with a spring boot application as the application using the root context, and the Geoserver but i didn't find any issues at all.

The steps I've followed are:

1. Create the Openshift app from the repository specified in the guide (tomcat7 + postgresql9.2 cartridges)
2. Clone the repo
3. Rename the `webapps/ROOT.war` to `webapps/geoserver.war`
4. Create a `pom.xml` file (see source below)
5. Include the source code of my application in the src folder (just a Spring Boot app with a RestController for the `/` entry point saying hello world.
6. Add the `deploy` action hook just as stated above
7. Push the code.

**pom.xml**

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>es.saljuama</groupId>
    <artifactId>geoserver</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>geoserver</name>
    <description>Geoserver demo project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Using this profile for my local machine, just the app using and embedded tomcat, with devtools, since i'm not sure if you want to make your app interact with the geoserver or not. -->
            <id>local</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>openshift</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <finalName>geoserver</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.6</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: But I can't get the Geoserver (the WAR) to run if I have the src folder and the pom.xml.

Comment: @LadyPeanut oh sorry, I didn't notice that the repository in the guide just provides the WAR artifact and some sample data, i thought it was the source code. So what is your intention exactly? to deploy the geoserver and your application in the same gear? or just the geoserver?

Comment: I want to have the geoserver and my own application (from source code) on the same gear

Comment: @LadyPeanut updated the answer with the information to deploy both.

Comment: I've seen the update, but it doesn't seem to work. Indeed, when I try to get to the application Geoserver, it shows me a 404 error. Although I don't understand the changes you have made on the pom-.xml (I haven't touched the file just in case). The deploy action_hook seems to work just fine, although it doesn't start the Geoserver application.

Comment: I didn't make changes to the pom, just stated that while you can modify the pom.xml to satisfy the requirements of your application, that part should be keept intact.  Can you update your question with the tomcat logs, to see what errors are happening? (with the rhc tool, you can see the logs with `rhc tail -a appname`)

Comment: another option is to ssh into the app and verify that the artifacts are deployed correctly, by browsing the ${OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_DIR}/webapps/ and check its contents, there you should find the ROOT.war, geoserver.war files and descriptors that indicate if the deployment failed (like ROOT.war.failed or similar)

Comment: @LadyPeanut after seeing your updates, seems that the geoserver.war is not being picked by the deployment scanner, could you try to add `touch ${OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_DIR}webapps/geoserver.war` after the `cp` instruction in the deploy action hook? That should trigger the deployment scanner.

Comment: @LadyPeanut i guess the `touch` instruction didn't fix anything, i'd need to further investigate what is causing the problem, but will need some time, will come back to you when i can.

Comment: @LadyPeanut tried to reproduce the problem, but i didn't have any issue, included the steps i followed.

Comment: Ugh. The steps I followed were: 1) Create the app on the web (tomcat 7) 2) Put the postgre cartridge 3) Download to local 4) Put the geoserver.war on the webapps directory 5) Put the deploy and pre_start_jobssews action hooks on the .openshift/action_hooks/ 6) Give execution permissions to the action_hooks 7) And then, push everything to the repository

Comment: @LadyPeanut did you miss the __pre_start__ action hook? there is a total of 3 action hooks. Btw, added a link to a repository in github with all the code (which will be available soon, still uploading)

Comment: It seems that it is running now. I don't know where the problem was, but it is solved now. Thank you very much.